# How to get flat lighting in Unity and C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm pretty new to lighting in Unity, but I've asked on Unity forums and pored over questions like http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/955346/flat-lighting-for-3d-game-with-orthographic-camera.html but I can't achieve the same lighting as Crossy Road - flat, vibrant colors but with shadows 
[image].

From tutorials I know I need a directional light, but all my directional lights wash out my colors and don't evenly distribute. Right now I have an ambient light, only problem is no shadows:

[image]

What can I do here? Are there specific settings to try?

Comment: You should post a picture of your attempts with the directional light since that's ultimately what's needed for the final result. We need to see the issues you're facing with it.

Comment: Crossy Road dude just used

bright colors.

honestly, that's all there is to it

Answer (score 1):

The shading is "flat" because the objects are:

- composed of faces that are generally at right angles to one another
- no curved surfaces
- shader should treat light sources as being at *infinity*
- shader should **not** vary colour as a function of a point on the face and light angle
- max diffuse shading
- zero specular shading

You may also want to turn on *hard shadows*

Comment: Yes Ive tried hard shadows, they work but again Im having an issue with the directional light not distributing light evenly

Comment: What do you mean by "not distributing light evenly"? Edit your answer and post a picture because by definition, a directional light is equidistance at all points. If you disable all light bouncing, light probes and other advanced lighting, the shadows will be even.